# Having a 3 divs layout. How can I make the middle div to stay below the other two?

Tags: css, layout, sass

I was searching a way to make a responsive design like so
I have 3 divs inside a parent div

```
<div style="display: flex">
  <div class="logo">some image here</div>

  <div class="menu-items">
    <a href="/home">Home</a>
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="login-logout">Here is the login component</div>
</div>
```

How can I make a responsive version of this to be something like this using only css and sass?

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column">
  <div style="display: flex">
    <div class="logo">some image here</div>

    <div class="login-logout">Here is the login component</div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu-items">
    <a href="/home">Home</a>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the middle div to stay bellow the other two

I have a guess that this can be possible using grid layout, but honestly I don't understand very much about it and prefer using flex. So if this could be achieved using flex I would be very much appreciated

Edit:
An image of how I want the layout to be.
[image: layout]

Comment: Could you show an image of the layout you want? A handdrawn sketch is fine. I'm not too clear at the moment about what you mean by 'below' (e.g. what are the relative widths of the 3 elements to be?).

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the reply. I will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flex is basically one dimensional whereas grid allows layout in two dimensions.

This snippet takes your code but sets the container to display grid.

grid-template areas are laid out for the wider screens in the ratio 2/3/1 and in the narrower ones in the ratio 2/1 in the top line.

Obviously you'll want to set the relative sizes suitable for your particular case.

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: 'logo logo menu menu menu login';
  gap: 2vw;
  padding: 2vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container>* {
  border: 3px solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 'logo logo login' 'menu menu menu';
  }
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
}

.menu-items {
  grid-area: menu;
}

.login-logout {
  grid-area: login;
}


/* borders added fordemo */

.logo {
  border-color: red;
}

.menu-items {
  border-color: blue;
}

.login-logout {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">some image here</div>

  <div class="menu-items">
    <a href="/home">Home</a> ...
  </div>

  <div class="login-logout">Here is the login component</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much, I will study more about grid layout, probably will be useful later on